# How to read this text ①② in a SJIS file?

Tags: java, csv, unicode

How to get these characters `①②`?

I'm using Java 1.6 to read the csv file (in SJIS encoding) which contains these characters, and I only get back this `��` when running the program.

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("examples/input.csv"));
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "SJIS");
        Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int ch;
        while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
            buffer.append((char)ch);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println(buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

### Input

Contents of `input.csv`:

```
"備考"
①②ランプ
```

#### Actual Output

```
 �@�Aランプ
```

#### Expected Output

```
"①②ランプ"
```

Comment: You need to provide an example of your code which will help show what is happening and how it has gone wrong.

Comment: I've just edited and added the code. @KevinPanko

Comment: So you want the [Unicode: 'circled digit one' (①)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2460/index.htm) and  [Unicode: 'circled digit two' (②)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2461/index.htm) to display in the console (Where exactly is your system out being directed?)? Have you read the official tutorial on Unicode? : [*"Oracle: The Java™ Tutorials | Unicode"*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html).

Comment: Hmm.. unfortunately ShiftJIS is not part of utf - but anyway, did you test setting the charset to utf-8 (`InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");`)? I also wonder it did work anyway, since "SJIS" seems not the standardized name in the IANA-registry (there its listed as `Shift_JIS `).

Comment: Thank you @Mr.Polywhirl, I have followed your suggestion, currently I still don't get the point.

Comment: @ florianb, I did that too, but that's not work. (It's only work if the file encode is UTF-8) but in my case, the input file is encoded with SJIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Shift-JIS character set does not contain the characters ① and ②.

Your file is not saved in standard [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), the encoding you get in Java under the name `SJIS`. It's actually Windows [code page 932](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), a Microsoft-specific extension of Shift-JIS that *does* include ①②. You can get this encoding in Java using the name `windows-932`.

Comment: Thank you very much @bobince. It worked like a charm as you said.

Comment: From your answer, now I get another question in mind, "how do we know the file is a standard encode or not?" because even I use the detect encode, it still return me the encode name is SJIS. 
This is another question actually just come to me, so I will look around to figure it out and come back with solution in case I find out. :)

Comment: There is no way to reliably detect encodings in general, I'm afraid; auto chardets are always going to produce the wrong result in many cases. For what it's worth, in the case of Shift-JIS it's safe to use `windows-932` as an alternative to `SJIS` as 932 is a superset of the standard encoding. For other standards-body-vs-Windows encoding differences this doesn't necessarily hold true though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you may need to set the encoding of the console/terminal that your program is using to print out to.

---

This may not be the answer you are looking for, but if you are using Eclipse, you can try the following. The output is correct based on your question.

### Eclipse IDE

In Eclipse, if you click on the down-arrow beside the run-button you should see the "Run Configurations..." option. If you select the "Common" tab, you should see a form field-set labeled "Encoding". Select the "Other" radio-button and change the selection to "UTF-8".

[image]

#### Working Example

I modified the code a bit, to load the file via the project. I also used `Character.toChars(ch)` instead of `(char) ch` as a more robust approach for parsing the character. The `Character.toChars` function *"Converts the specified character (Unicode code point) to its UTF-16 representation stored in a char array."*

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            FileInputStream fis = loadResource("resources/input.csv");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
            Reader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

            int ch;
            while ((ch = in.read()) > -1) {
                buffer.append(Character.toChars(ch));
            }
            in.close();

            System.out.println(buffer.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final FileInputStream loadResource(String name) throws FileNotFoundException, URISyntaxException {
        return new FileInputStream(new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource(name).toURI()));
    }
}
```

Comment: This way doesn't work @Mr Polywhirl. The characters will be broken when you use to "UTF-8" for the SJIS encode file.
Edit1:
it will be looked like this:
���l
 
�@�A���

Comment: @thangpt: OK, so it is alright if I delete this then?

Comment: Thank you @Mr Polywhirl, but could you please keep it there? because we can help another guys who has the same issue get the experience without try many ways.