# Japanese fullwidth character ー is getting garbled when converted to SHIFT_JIS in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, fileoutputstream, shift-jis

In my application, I am reading the data (Japanese text) from DB (UTF-8) and trying to write the output in SHIFT_JIS file format. However, full width ー (817C hex code in shift JIS) is getting converted as ? in the output file.

Here is the sample program to test it

```java
public class ShiftJisTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "東１－１";
        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("output_data"), "SHIFT_JIS"))) {
            writer.write(text);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
東１?１
```

Hex Code value of output:

```
93 8C 82 50 3F 82 50
```

Garbled character in HEX: `3F`, expected was `81 7C`

Comment: I suggest reducing that example string to fewest possible characters needed to show your issue.

Comment: Here is the input & output for character having issue.
Input: 
String text = "１－";
Output: １?

Comment: [Unicode replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)) is used when the encoding doesn't support the character. I'd say you either have the wrong kind of `－`, or this is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-4852917) in SHIFT_JIS support.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/Shift_JIS/list.htm) `0x817C` is [U+2212 minus sign](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm). This reproduces on my machine, as in the hyphen is translated to `3F/?`.

Comment: Those two characters in the second Comment are 65297 & 65293 decimal. See [code run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/xy1TOy). Character names are Fullwidth Digit One and Fullwidth Hyphen-Minus.

Comment: If you are using Windows then in your `FileOutputStream()` constructor replace "SHIFT_JIS" with "windows-932". I just tested that change, and it fixes your problem. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29784905/2985643) for [How to read this text ①② in a SJIS file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29778255/2985643) Your question looks like a duplicate of that one. (If you are not using Windows then specify your O/S.)

Comment: From testing it looks like you can also specify "windows-31j" or "MS932" or "cp932" instead of "windows-932". I don't know which of those names (if any) are supported in non-Windows environments.

Comment: Looks like CP932/MS932 gives the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that character is not in Shift_Jis:

```
goose@t410:/tmp$ uniname '\uFF0D'
The name for codepoint \uFF0D is FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS
The char is －
goose@t410:/tmp$ echo -en '\uFF0D' | iconv -t SHIFT-JIS
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0
```

Comment: Although depending on the [converter](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122942/incorrect-encoding-Shiftjis-for-some-special-characters) it could/should be converted to the minus sign.

Comment: This may explain the OP's problem, but it doesn't solve it.

Comment: The solution is to not use non-existent characters. Substitution can be used but that's arbitrary and subjective

Comment: No, that is not the solution at all. The solution is to select an appropriate encoding for the text being processed. The OP's problem arose only because an inappropriate encoding was used.

Comment: Presumably the @Prince has a reason for using Shift_Jis. If he hasn't then the solution is simple - use UTF-8.